# How to make a monochrome like this?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, logo, pathfinder

[image]

I don't know how to call this but how to make a monochrome like the one on bottom.
The exclusion (white), but originally it doesn't overlap.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no trick or filter to making all-monochrome versions of your logo like this. I guess this designer simply drew the white contours so they would suggest the corresponding shapes in the colour version. Monochromising a logo can be quite an art.

Answer (score 1):

In Illustrator...

Select all, then choose `Edit > Edit Colors > Convert to Greyscale`.

Then select and adjust values for individual areas as needed.

Answer (score -3):

Select the all white areas around the logo, that which is not logo. Then invert that selection and fill with black.

Then add details to taste.

Comment: This is not a working solution for Illustration. It would work in Raster images but especially for a logo will not be the best way to do it.

Comment: @Ryan same thing works in illustrator, just while normally you cut a square into pieces with pathfinder. There is still the coloribg tool that works exactly like raster fill. its the same concept both conceptually and literally on a technical level.

Comment: @joojaa I would argue that Illustrators Live Paint Bucket Tool, while on the surface may appear to be a "color fill" tool is far from any raster bucket fill method, both creatively and technically. But that's a discussion for another time.

Comment: @scott fair enough but to me the difference is like the difference of a continuous function and a discrete z function. Finding borders and filling is just the equivalent algorithm in discrete versus continuous math. Because sampling is obviously worn't work in  continuous math you need to analyze the situation. But then what would i know its not like ive ever made my own fill routine. Oh wait...

Comment: Imagine the logo wasn't on white. Imagine it was on a green filled circle. Select that, invert the selection to get all the components of the logo that are not that circle, then fill them with black. It's the same process whether you think in terms of bitmaps or vector objects. Exactly. It's just much easier to select the invert when you want to do this because then there's no deselection process required.

Comment: Select and invert is not logical for **Adobe Illustrator**. You're arguing a silly point.

Comment: SELECT>INVERSE. Not logical? You must be the world's best object selector. And given the propensity of Illustrator's selectUnder to fail abysmally, all power to you. I use selection inversion in Illustrator more than deselect or shift selecting for this reason, and one other... Illustrators drag select is an ALL TOUCHES selection by default, so this inversion of selection is incredibly fast and easier to live with than trying to do sub selections of layered objects. Try it. It will save you a lot of time normally spent locking down objects and layers to avoid extraneous drag selections.

Comment: @Confused You should edit the clarification from the comments to your answer!